# How to rotate box shadow around a text?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, box-shadow

I'm studying HTML/CSS and I found a very interesting example of rotating box shadows. I thought I'd try to use it, but I can't get my head around rotating the shadows around my text.

The example I found has a  like `<div class="rotate-shadows"></div>` and CSS like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.rotate-shadows {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
}
.rotate-shadows:after,
.rotate-shadows:before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.rotate-shadows:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 250, 250, 0.6), inset 20px 0 0 rgba(0, 200, 200, 0.6), inset 0 -20px 0 rgba(0, 150, 200, 0.6), inset -20px 0 0 rgba(0, 200, 250, 0.6);
  animation: rotate-before 2s -0.5s linear infinite;
}
.rotate-shadows:after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 0 rgba(250, 250, 0, 0.6), inset 20px 0 0 rgba(250, 200, 0, 0.6), inset 0 -20px 0 rgba(250, 150, 0, 0.6), inset -20px 0 0 rgba(250, 100, 0, 0.6);
  animation: rotate-after 2s -0.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate-after {
  0% {transform: rotateZ(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);}
  50% {transform: rotateZ(180deg) scaleX(0.82) scaleY(0.95);}
  100% {transform: rotateZ(360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);}
}
@keyframes rotate-before {
  0% {transform: rotateZ(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);}
  50% {transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scaleX(0.95) scaleY(0.85);}
  100% {transform: rotateZ(-360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);}
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate-shadows"></div>
```

I figured out that I don't need `body {}`, figured out where I can change the color of the shadows, scale, etc. But I can't get which part is responsible for the shape of the shadows.

Can I make the shadows go around my text like an animated frame:

> Классная шляпная шляпа с широкими полями всего за два куська. Да-да!
>   Это не опечатка! Всего два динозаврических укуса и шляпа ваша!

Where do I need to put my text to have shadows rotating around it?
And how can I change the shape of shadows?

I just want to understand.

Comment: Put text inside the div and add `display: flex; justify-content: center;align-items: center;` to `.rotate-shadows`, the shadows are being made using inset shadow on pseudo-Elements, changing the shape will involve playing along with the values of the [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly is this what you need?

> I added an extra `div` inside to wrap the `text` if that is not an issue? this div acts based on the parent's position. making it in the middle.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.rotate-shadows {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.rotate-shadows:after,
.rotate-shadows:before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.rotate-shadows:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 250, 250, 0.6), inset 20px 0 0 rgba(0, 200, 200, 0.6), inset 0 -20px 0 rgba(0, 150, 200, 0.6), inset -20px 0 0 rgba(0, 200, 250, 0.6);
  animation: rotate-before 2s -0.5s linear infinite;
}

.rotate-shadows:after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 0 rgba(250, 250, 0, 0.6), inset 20px 0 0 rgba(250, 200, 0, 0.6), inset 0 -20px 0 rgba(250, 150, 0, 0.6), inset -20px 0 0 rgba(250, 100, 0, 0.6);
  animation: rotate-after 2s -0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-after {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg) scaleX(0.82) scaleY(0.95);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-before {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scaleX(0.95) scaleY(0.85);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate-shadows">
  <div id="text">
    Once upon a time in Stackoverflow!!
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need the content in the single `Div` then:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.rotate-shadows {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.rotate-shadows:after,
.rotate-shadows:before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.rotate-shadows:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 250, 250, 0.6), inset 20px 0 0 rgba(0, 200, 200, 0.6), inset 0 -20px 0 rgba(0, 150, 200, 0.6), inset -20px 0 0 rgba(0, 200, 250, 0.6);
  animation: rotate-before 2s -0.5s linear infinite;
}

.rotate-shadows:after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 0 rgba(250, 250, 0, 0.6), inset 20px 0 0 rgba(250, 200, 0, 0.6), inset 0 -20px 0 rgba(250, 150, 0, 0.6), inset -20px 0 0 rgba(250, 100, 0, 0.6);
  animation: rotate-after 2s -0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-after {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg) scaleX(0.82) scaleY(0.95);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-before {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) scaleX(0.95) scaleY(0.85);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate-shadows"> Once upon a time in Stackoverflow!!
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need flexbox on `#text`

Comment: But if I refer to `body` tag, won't my whole page will have the style attributes "margin, display", etc.?

Comment: Of-course you can! I just added another snippet for you,  I made another `Div` to make it simpler. Hope it helps!

Comment: @VladimirMarkiev did the answer helped you?

Comment: @Manjuboyz It helped, thank you! My text was still overlapped by shadows, then I added padding and now, even if I resize the div no overlapping occurs. But I'm struggling to understand how to change the position of the div. If I change parameters of `.rotate-shadows {` it doesn't affect anything for some reason.

Comment: The position should take care of that if you're looking at in the middle, incase if you're moving the shadow to different position then yeah you have to tweak a code to make in align!.